# Data transformation and Transpose in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

looking for help on converting data from one format to another -

If you want to see data in sheet is here - 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yO90XjjN2c80ReYMIXTdS7e8SLb2NNMRNqiXbqR8J2k/edit?pli=1#gid=555602833

Note: I want to do this in MS Excel and not in google sheet.

[image]

Description - 
1. Transpose primary data set and organize data so that options are shown as columns.
2. If there are multiple rows for same product and same option, need to sum it up and add as one row.
3. If products are not available for certain option then we need to update that cell as 'NA'
4. 'Primary set of data' may contain multiple rows, but it will have only 3 options at given point of time.
5. Above 3 scenrios are just for explanation of this problem, I want to develop one table which is dynamic
 and changes are reflected as I make updates to data

Answer (score 0):

For varying amounts of data, a PivotTable works well. It will not give you exactly the format you are looking for, but changing the order is as simple as moving the fields around in the Values box. An added advantage is that it also provides totals for you automatically (if you want that).

Of course, you could also build out a separate table that does a "GETPIVOTDATA" function to pull in and format the information how you like. The pivot just does the heavy lifting of aggregating the data for you, but it's not very flexible with how that data is displayed.

**PivotTable Example:**

[image: PivotTable Example]

**PivotTable Fields:**

[image: PivotTable Fields]